# How do you create charts using different sets of data of the same table?

Tags: google-sheets

I've never used google sheets in my life and I'm trying to make different charts from different sets of data from the same table. For example I have the following table:
[image]

and i would like to make a chart using this set of data:
[image]

and then make another chart from this set of data:
[image]

but as you can see, doing it in this way it also gives me the data of the previous days.
Selecting only the numbers without the first row it doesn't give me the correct legend. How can I make charts using the same header but different sets of data?

Comment: Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Chart editor, set the data range to `A1:D1,A4:D` and choose **Combine ranges vertically**.

Alternatively, **Insert > Sheet** and use a `filter()` or `query()` formula in the new sheet to pick the rows you want to plot. Then insert a chart based on the data in the new sheet.